# No Matching Function

Tags: solidity

Im starting to learn Solidity, and i have some issues when i try when i try `npx hardhat run`

The error itself:

```
TypeError: no matching function (argument="key", value="format", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=6.6.2)
    at makeError (C:\Users\santi\OneDrive\Documents\PROYECTOS\Development\Solidity\my-wave-portal\node_modules\ethers\src.ts\utils\errors.ts:670:21)
    at assert (C:\Users\santi\OneDrive\Documents\PROYECTOS\Development\Solidity\my-wave-portal\node_modules\ethers\src.ts\utils\errors.ts:694:25)
    at assertArgument (C:\Users\santi\OneDrive\Documents\PROYECTOS\Development\Solidity\my-wave-portal\node_modules\ethers\src.ts\utils\errors.ts:706:5)
    at Interface.getFunctionName (C:\Users\santi\OneDrive\Documents\PROYECTOS\Development\Solidity\my-wave-portal\node_modules\ethers\src.ts\abi\interface.ts:542:23)      
    at buildWrappedMethod (C:\Users\santi\OneDrive\Documents\PROYECTOS\Development\Solidity\my-wave-portal\node_modules\ethers\src.ts\contract\contract.ts:334:34)
    at BaseContract.getFunction (C:\Users\santi\OneDrive\Documents\PROYECTOS\Development\Solidity\my-wave-portal\node_modules\ethers\src.ts\contract\contract.ts:849:22)   
    at Object.get (C:\Users\santi\OneDrive\Documents\PROYECTOS\Development\Solidity\my-wave-portal\node_modules\ethers\src.ts\contract\contract.ts:747:39)
    at Function.from (C:\Users\santi\OneDrive\Documents\PROYECTOS\Development\Solidity\my-wave-portal\node_modules\ethers\src.ts\abi\interface.ts:1259:33)
    at new ContractFactory (C:\Users\santi\OneDrive\Documents\PROYECTOS\Development\Solidity\my-wave-portal\node_modules\ethers\src.ts\contract\factory.ts:53:33)
    at getContractFactoryByAbiAndBytecode (C:\Users\santi\OneDrive\Documents\PROYECTOS\Development\Solidity\my-wave-portal\node_modules\@nomicfoundation\hardhat-ethers\src\internal\helpers.ts:309:10) {
  code: 'INVALID_ARGUMENT',
  argument: 'key',
  value: 'format'
}
```

The script:

```
const main = async () => {
  const waveContractFactory = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("WavePortal");
  console.log(waveContractFactory)
  const waveContract = await waveContractFactory.deploy();
/*   console.log(waveContract); */
  await hre.ethers.deployContract(waveContract);
  /*     await .deployed() */
  await waveContract.waitForDeployment();
  const address = await waveContract.getAddress();
  console.log("this is the ADDRESS",address)
  console.log("Contract deployed to: ", address);
};

const runMain = async () => {
  try {
    await main();
    process.exit(0);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    process.exit(1);
  }
};

runMain();
```

And the contract itself:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

import "hardhat/console.sol";

contract WavePortal{
    constructor(){
        console.log("Hola!");
    }
}
```

i understand that solidity 6 has a lot of differences from older versions, but i dont find my mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use either contractFactory.deploy() or ethers.deployContract(), not both.

As you are already using the contractFactory, you can just remove the `await hre.ethers.deployContract(waveContract)` line and it should work.

Comment: Thanks @ceseshi ! It works for me!!